# Firebase data deleted when you delete different data with same key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I delete the first node "List" in Firebase, the second node "List 2" is automatically deleted. I think this is happening due to same key of child of both nodes. Is there any way to stop another node from being deleting?
[image: My Firebase Database]

Here's my code which I'm using to copy data from "List" to "List 2" and then delete the node "List". When I delete the one node the other also get deletd.

```
ref.child("List").child(cardTitle).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                                                    ref.child("SHOP_ITEM").child("List 2).setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                                                                    ref.child("SHOP_ITEM").child("List").removeValue();

                                                                }

                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                                }
                                                            });
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using to delete the values

Comment: If you delete it directly from firebase console then the same thing will happen.

Comment: I just tried that and it did not happen: http://imgur.com/a/lfcVR please provide more steps and see if you can reproduce.

Comment: I also tried it and it didn't happen

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6VEs1ADgFqrZ1F3ZGJGMnRoMGM   Please check out this video I made while deleting from firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I used a work around; I simply added a cancel value to it. Something like `cancel:"true"`.

In your case `DATABASEREF1 = List1` and `DATABASEREF2 = List2`..

This was what worked for me. Here is the code:

```
DATABASEREF1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        HashMap<String,String> hMdataSnapshot = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        hMdataSnapshot.put("canceled","true");

        DATABASEREF2.setValue(hMdataSnapshot).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                DATABASEREF1.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //DO SOMETHING
                        } else {
                           //DO SOMETHING 
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               //DO SOMETHING
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```